# Increasing the particular partition size in EBS

Tags: linux, partition, amazon-ebs

I have a ec2 system with Suse12sp3 and have following file system

```
ip-10-XX-XX-1XX:/ # lsblk
NAME    MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
xvda    202:0    0   100G  0 disk
└─xvda1 202:1    0   100G  0 part /
xvdf    202:80   0   500G  0 disk
├─xvdf1 202:81   0  93.1G  0 part /hana/shared
├─xvdf2 202:82   0  93.1G  0 part /hana/log
└─xvdf3 202:83   0 186.3G  0 part /hana/data
xvdg    202:96   0    20G  0 disk
└─xvdg1 202:97   0    20G  0 part /test
```

I have been trying to increase the size of xvdf3 using the following commands, but it is not working as expected:

```
ip-10-xx-xx-xxx:/ # growpart /dev/xvdf 3
NOCHANGE: partition 3 is size 390625280. it cannot be grown
```

It is giving me an error, that It can't be grown, can you suggest what am doing wrong here.

Initially, these partitions were created as shown below:

```
parted /dev/xvdf 
mklabel gpt 
unit GB
mkpart primary 0.00GB  100.00GB
mkpart primary 100.00GB  200.00 Gb
mkpart primary 200.00GB  400.00 Gb
print
quit
```

Please suggest how partition expansion can be done

Comment: It looks like `/dev/xvdf3` maybe mounted to `/hana/data` - try `umount /hana/data` then try your `growpart` again?

Comment: Well, that solved the issue, I am pity new to the linux, hence made that silly mistake. Thanks a lot for your inputs.

Comment: Cool! Glad that worked! I posted this as an answer ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like `/dev/xvdf3` maybe mounted to `/hana/data`

Try `umount /hana/data` then try your `growpart` again.

Linux doesn't allow most modifications to partitions while they are mounted or in use in some way.